# Configurable products and layered navigation

Tags: configurable-product, price, layered-navigation, simple-product

Hopefully someone can help, I'm creating configurable products for the first time, with the end goal resulting in customers being able to refine their search using layered navigation.

For example: customer chooses divan beds, and then wants to see all the beds available in king size, at the moment all the king size beds are available but only show the base price, not the price of the king size simple product price.

What we need is the results to show the customer the price of that size (which has been set in the simple products.) Some sites get around this by listing "price from" but this is not ideal.

I'm not sure if there is something we've missed or if there is some custom coding / extension required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your magento version??

Comment: Using Magento version 1.9.2.4

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use [SCP(Simple Configurable Product Extension)](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple). This will automatically show the actual price of which product option is selected.

Comment: Would this also work in the layered navigation and show the prices of the selected sizes?

Comment: Thanks, this extension might work, not sure that it will work with 1.9. Might be worth a backup and install just to see.